# Travelling to France by eurotunnel with UK issued EU Family member residence permit

Tags: immigration, france, eu-spouses, europe

Hey i will be travelling to paris over the weekend with my husband who is a Portuguese national. I jave an Indian passport and UK issued EU family member residence biometric card. Will i have to apply for a separate visa or can i take our marriage certificate with me??

Answer (score 2):

If you did need a visa, it would be rather too late at this point.  Fortunately, you do not need one.

Your passport and residence card should suffice, but it won't hurt for you to bring a marriage certificate as well.  If you do not have your marriage certificate, you can bring any other evidence of your marriage, but you probably won't need it, and it is in any event not required.  The controlling language of the [freedom of movement directive](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616) is found in Article 5.  The first three of its five sections follow:

> Article 5
>
> Right of entry
>
> 1. Without prejudice to the provisions on travel documents applicable to national border controls, Member States shall grant Union citizens leave to enter their territory with a valid identity card or passport and **shall grant family members who are not nationals of a Member State leave to enter their territory with a valid passport.**
>
>    No entry visa or equivalent formality may be imposed on Union citizens.
> 2. Family members who are not nationals of a Member State shall only be required to have an entry visa in accordance with Regulation (EC) No 539/2001 or, where appropriate, with national law. **For the purposes of this Directive, possession of the valid residence card referred to in Article 10 shall exempt such family members from the visa requirement.**
>
>    Member States shall grant such persons every facility to obtain the necessary visas. Such visas shall be issued free of charge as soon as possible and on the basis of an accelerated procedure.
> 3. **The host Member State shall not place an entry or exit stamp in the passport of family members who are not nationals of a Member State provided that they present the residence card provided for in Article 10.**

(emphasis added)

You may be asked to prove that the man you are traveling with is indeed your husband, but it is unlikely.  If you are asked to prove it, though, there's no specific document required.  Most officers will be satisfied with a verbal declaration.

Comment: Hey.... My wife posted this.... Will she need a travel insurance??

Comment: @user59683 Travel insurance is not required to clear passport control, but it might be necessary, or at least wise, for other reasons. For example, does she have an EHIC card?

Comment: Nope, she doesn't. Also while booking the ticket i didnt take the insurance offered by eurotunnel. My car insurance covers europe. I hope thats ok.

Comment: @user59683 car insurance generally does not cover people who become sick or are injured because of something that has nothing to do with the covered car.  But to stay on point, a lack of such insurance cannot be a basis for excluding you or your wife from France for a stay of up to three months.